# Blogger template problems

Tags: blogger, blogger-templates

I'm trying to use this template:

Demo: http://templatehybridgallery.blogspot.com/

On their demo there are eight posts on the front page, but when I put it on my site, there are always three posts on the odd numbered pages and two posts on the even numbered pages.

Can someone shed some light on where the problem might be (I know it's in the html)?

Comment: share your origianl blogger url or code.