# Good Photo Gallery template for BLOGGER (or tutorial)

Tags: blogger, blogger-templates

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Blogger template problems](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/11633/blogger-template-problems)

**Does anyone know of any good (free) Blogger template for Photo Galleries?**

I need something Simple, just for photos (no need for text).

I found a wonderful one, but I can't get it to work properly (it doesn't display always the same number of posts on the page, and it only displays 3 posts, not like their example)

- Demo: http://templatehybridgallery.blogspot.com/

Ps.: If you know of any good tutorial for me to make my own, I'd apreciate it too